# renaming columns R with memisc package

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a subset and rename my columns with the memisc package.

This is my Code. The variable v_217 should be just the cases with more than 20.

```
library (memisc)
dat <- subset(dat,
              v_217 > 20,
                select = c(
                "mann" = v_382,
                "Alter" = v_1033,
                "Bildung" = v_384,
                "Klimawandel?" = v_217)
    )
names(dat)
[1] "v_382"  "v_1033" "v_384"  "v_217"
```

It do not get a warning, but it just doesn't rename the objetcs. Does soemone now why? My Professor really want me to do it with the memisc package, so I kinda have to do it with memisc and no other package.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know the `memisc` package, but base `subset()` ignores named vectors, so just does selection, no renaming. For instance, `subset(airquality, Temp > 80, select = c(A = Ozone, B =Temp))`

Comment: as @caldwellst said, just delete the `"`. See also the help `?memisc::subset()`